# Creating a category in discordpy with permissions that only a specific role can join and type in

Tags: python, discord.py

Looking to make a category with text and voice channels only visible by a specific role (which is in the same command)... here's what I have so far but I am a bit lost when it comes to adding the permissions to the category..

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def createfriendgroup(ctx, role_name):
    guild = ctx.guild
    await guild.create_category(role_name)
    category = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, name = role_name)
    await guild.create_role(name = role_name)
    await guild.create_text_channel(f"{role_name}-private-tc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
    await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{role_name}-private-vc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
```

So I've created the category, the text, and the voice channel (both with synced permissions), but do now know how set the permissions inside the category, so any help would be absolutely amazing! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options, either do [`CategoryChannel.set_permissions`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.set_permissions) or [`CategoryChannel.edit`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.CategoryChannel.edit)

1. **set_permissions()**

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def createfriendgroup(ctx, role_name):
    guild = ctx.guild
    category = await guild.create_category(role_name)
    role = await guild.create_role(name = role_name)
    await category.set_permissions(role, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
    await category.set_permissions(ctx.guild.default_role, read_messages=False, connect=False)
    await guild.create_text_channel(f"{role_name}-private-tc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
    await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{role_name}-private-vc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
```

2. **Using Overwrites**

```py
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def createfriendgroup(ctx, role_name):
    guild = ctx.guild
    category = await guild.create_category(role_name)
    role = await guild.create_role(name = role_name)
    overwrites = {
                    ctx.guild.default_role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False, connect=False),
                    role: discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
                  }
    await category.edit(overwrites=overwrites)
    await guild.create_text_channel(f"{role_name}-private-tc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
    await guild.create_voice_channel(f"{role_name}-private-vc", category = category, sync_permissions=True)
```

Comment: thank you very much! This really cleared out how to use overwrights and category.set_permissions, thank you very much!