# Problem in create private category in Discord.py

Tags: python, discord, bots

```
role = await guild.create_role(name=role_name, colour=0x1eff00)
category = await guild.create_category(role_name)
await category.set_permissions(role, view_channel=True, read_messages=True, send_messages=True, connect=True, speak=True)
```

I wanted to create a private category, but I'm not able to, I can only create non-category channels, when I create the category, only users with the rule should be able to see it, but they are seeing all users

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question can be answered with a simple Google search, so here:

[Creating a category in discordpy with permissions that only a specific role can join and type in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63975108/creating-a-category-in-discordpy-with-permissions-that-only-a-specific-role-can)